# Read the image value pixel by pixel

Tags: sd-card

I need your help in SD card and image. It's been a week since I have involved with this problem, So I wish you can help me.

Here is the problem:

I saved a photo to the SD card and now I want to read the color information of each pixel and put the servo in a definite position based of the pixel color.
I want to read pixel by pixel information in a row and after completing a row reed the next row.

The image has 2000*2000 pixels in BMP format, but I can change the format if it is necessary and the picture consist 100 colors, so it means the servo should have 100 different position.

I can also take photo information as a CSV file with 2000 rows and 2000 columns as int values and save the .csv file to the SD card.

it would be grate if someone can help me.

Comment: Please add any code/sketch that you have already written. Also add more details with what specifically you need help with. This is very unclear right now.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: are you saying that you would like the servo to be positioned 4 million times?